# On improving the upper bound $I(m^2) \leq \frac{2p}{p+1}$, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, inequalities, open-problems, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

(Preamble: This question is an offshoot of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4275148/28816) to an MSE question with the same title.)

Denote the *classical sum of the divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ and the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Since we have
$$I(m^2) \leq \dfrac{2p}{p+1}$$
and because $p^k m^2$ is perfect, then we have
$$I(p^k)I(m^2) = I(p^k m^2) = 2$$
where we have used the fact that the abundancy index function is *multiplicative*.

Hence, we obtain (via iteration)
$$\text{First iteration: } I(m^2) \leq I(p^k)I(m^2)\cdot\dfrac{p}{p+1} \leq 2I(p^k)\cdot\dfrac{p^2}{(p+1)^2}$$
$$\text{Second iteration: } I(m^2) \leq \bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^2 {I(m^2)} \cdot\dfrac{p^2}{(p+1)^2} \leq 2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^2 \cdot\dfrac{p^3}{(p+1)^3}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\ldots$$
by recursively replacing $2$ with $I(p^k)I(m^2)$ and then bounding $I(m^2)$ from above by $2p/(p+1)$.

Note that, at the $n^{\text{th}}$ iteration, we have the inequality
$$I(m^2) \leq 2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n \cdot \dfrac{p^{n+1}}{(p+1)^{n+1}}.$$
Repeating the process *ad infinitum*, we get
$$I(m^2) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n \cdot \dfrac{p^{n+1}}{(p+1)^{n+1}}} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\dfrac{2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n}{\dfrac{(p+1)^{n+1}}{p^{n+1}}}}$$
$$= \dfrac{2p}{p+1}\cdot\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\dfrac{\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n}{\bigg(I(p)\bigg)^n}},$$
where the limit is of the indeterminate form
$$\dfrac{+\infty}{+\infty}.$$

Hence, we may apply [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), by considering
$$h(p) = \dfrac{\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n}{\bigg(I(p)\bigg)^n}$$
as a function of $p$.

(Also, note that there is "currently no L'Hôpital's rule for multiple variable limits".  The closest thing that I could find on arXiv is this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0363) by Gary R. Lawlor.)

*I tried working on applying L'Hôpital's rule to $h(p)$, by asking for help from WolframAlpha, however the computations are a mess.*

Here is my inquiry:

> **QUESTION:** Is it possible to simplify the computations, via say, some recursive rule that I do not know about?

Comment: After performing some manual computations, I think all that remains is
$$I(m^2) \leq \dfrac{2p}{p+1}\cdot\Bigg(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\dfrac{\dfrac{{\partial}^n}{\partial {p^n}} \bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)}{\dfrac{{\partial}^n}{\partial {p^n}} \bigg(I(p)\bigg)}}\Bigg)$$
although I am not $100\%$ sure.

Comment: By inspection, we obtain
$$\dfrac{{\partial}^n}{\partial {p^n}} \bigg(I(p)\bigg)=\dfrac{{(-1)^n}\cdot{n!}}{p^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: Also, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Compute+the+limit+of+%28%28%28p%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+1%29%2F%28p%5Ek+%28p+-+1%29%29%29%5En%29%2F%28%28%28p%2B1%29%2Fp%29%5En%29+as+n+approaches+infinity) computes
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\dfrac{\Bigg(I(p^k)\Bigg)^n}{\Bigg(I(p)\Bigg)^n}}=0$$
when
$$I(p) > I(p^k),$$
which I know to be false, since $I(p^k) \geq I(p)$ holds in general.  Does this mean that the limit is nonzero?